# Javascript – absolute or relative URL in history.pushState

Tags: javascript, url, pushstate

Is there a difference in using an absolute or relative url as the `history.pushState` url parameter?

```
history.pushState(null, null, absolute/relative)
```

I'm asking because the CMS PHP environment handles absolute urls better than relative urls and before I proceed with the code work, I'd like to know if I can even use absolute urls.

The absolute URL is always from the same `https` origin (the same website basically).

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything on that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [Mdn history.pushState() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

the last parameter, the URL, can be relative or absolute (with the same origin).
If you use relative Url is more Comfortable:
For example if your starting page is:

```
https://www.google.com/bar.html
```

and you do:

```
history.pushState(null,null,"foo.html");
```

you will get 
    https://www.google.com/foo.html

Note that this does not make a request to the server but it changes the url in the location address bar and in `location.href`

But you can use also an absolute URL according to the documentation

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, unfortunately I only can it make properly with absolute URLs, but if apparently that's not a problem, I'll keep the absolute URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I call `pushState` on a link with `href:projects/test` it'll go to `https://example.com/projects/test`, when I `window.popstate` back it goes to `http://example.com/projects` BUT when I then popstate forward it goes to `http://example.com/projects/projects/test`

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot, the URL is not working because it's a relative URL to the current path where it should be a relative URL to the website with a slash "/".